# Simple JS linter for checking one file, no project?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, lint

I am new to Visual Studio Code, and have discovered the world of linting.

I am not working on a new express project, and so there's no package.json...

How do I lint my single JS file using VSCode, without doing 'npm init' etc.?

FYI, I have looked at ESLint, and StandardJS - VSCode extensions, but they need to be added to a project, which i don't have; I just have a single JS file that needs linting.

Cheers

Comment: I would check out the VSCode [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript) on using javascript. Basically, it comes with built in JS support through IntelliSense and you can go a little further by setting up a `jsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Download the ESLint extension as well.

Comment: @Mark, Cheers, I have already downloaded it... But from what I can gather, it needs setting up with a project, which I don't have.

Comment: You are right - I missed your `FYI` in the question.

Comment: For a single file I would just use https://www.jslint.com/ or https://jshint.com/